# Нужна ли запятая перед причастным оборотом «к нему относящегося»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Не хочу знать ни его, ни всего к нему относящегося.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Не хочу знать ни его, ни всего () к нему относящегося.***

Интересное предложение. Вроде бы всё хорошо, да не очень…

Так, значит, «к нему относящегося»  – это причастный оборот? И тогда «всего» – определяемое слово, то есть субстантивированное местоимение? Вот и у Розенталя тоже в этой теме определительным назван причастный оборот: *Все опоздавшие на лекцию стояли в коридоре.*

Но, может быть, в коридоре всё-таки стояли именно  «опоздавшие на лекцию», а «все» – это определение. Так как-то логичнее, **то есть субстантивированным  здесь можно считать причастие.** Тем более что далее у Розенталя следуют примеры, где оборот действительно является определительным, а про субстантивацию местоимения ничего не сказано: ***Эти недавно опубликованные*** стихи были написаны много лет назад.  **Ваш проверенный на практике** метод заслуживает внимания.

А еще интереснее дальше:

Но если определительный оборот имеет характер **пояснения** или уточнения, то он обособляется (выделяется запятыми): *Всё, **связанное с железной дорогой**, до сих пор овеяно для меня поэзией путешествий* (Пауст.) — определительное местоимение **субстантивировано.**

Вот мы и добрались до субстантивированного местоимения и обособленного причастного оборота. Тогда можно предположить, что запятую (по Розенталю) надо ставить в заданном предложении: *Не хочу знать ни его, ни всего, **к нему относящегося**.* Или, по крайней мере, можно поставить при таком грамматическом разборе.

И если сравнить интонацию вариантов, то выбор будет, возможно, в пользу **обособленного оборота,** так как тесная связь  между местоимением и распространенным оборотом (ввиду наличия дополнения **«к нему»)** как-то не очень просматривается. А эта тесная связь при отсутствии запятой (по Розенталю) совершенно необходима.

(1) *Не хочу знать ни егО, ни всего к нему относЯщегося.*

(2) *Не хочу знать ни егО, ни всегО, к нему относЯщегося.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134388/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon--------).

Comment: Да, потому что новые комментарии не поднимают вопрос в списке "Текущие". Тема сложная. Мне тоже бы хотелось официальной информации. Сперва думал над такими вариантами: *Не хочу знать как его, так и того, что с ним связано. Не хочу знать что его, что всего с ним связанного.* То есть о таких союзах.

Comment: К этой теме пришлось вернуться. Здесь имеет место принцип однородности. Пример по другой теме (потому что там есть правило): *Он ушёл из-за усталости и из-за тогО, что был расстроен.* То есть нужна запятая из-за однородности. Причастный оборот и придаточное — сопоставимые вещи (вчера вы их сопоставляли). В любом случае в примере из вопроса это способствует запятой.

Answer (score 10):

*Не хочу знать ни его, ни всего к нему относящегося.*

Предложение составлено верно, запятая после ***всего*** не требуется, так как это слово нуждается в определении, то есть само по себе (без причастного оборота) не будет выражать нужного смысла.

[**Согласованные определения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=273) (Розенталь)

> 4. Определительный оборот, стоящий после определительного, указательного или притяжательного местоимения, тесно примыкает к нему и запятой не отделяется: *Всё **смеющееся, весёлое, отмеченное печатью юмора** было ему мало доступно* (Кор.); *Все **опоздавшие на лекцию** стояли в коридоре.*