# Причастный оборот. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

*Доброе утро всем, поздно спать ложащимся.*
В этом предложении нужна запятая или нет? Ведь тут причастный оборот, если не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

**Доброе утро всем, поздно спать ложащимся.**

Ложа́щийся — причастие (наст. вр.) от *ложиться*.
Запятая необходима, так как причастный оборот, стоящий **после** определяемого слова, выделяется запятыми. [Всем (каким?) ложащимся поздно спать.]

С обособлением:

> Теперь  море сияло уже не сплошь,  а  лишь  в  двух  местах:  длинной  полосой  на  самом горизонте и десятком режущих глаза звезд, попеременно вспыхивающих в зеркале волны, **осторожно ложащейся на песок** (В. Катаев. Белеет парус одинокий).

Без обособления (причастный оборот стоит **перед** определяемым словом):

> **Всегда рано ложащийся спать** Кеша медленно танцует возле камина с девушкой, абсолютно веселая и счастливая Маша уплетает что-то белое и, очевидно, вкусное (Д. Донцова. Спят усталые игрушки).

Написание без запятых возможно, если причастие субстантивируется — то есть употребляется в роли имени существительного.
*Доброе утро поздно спать ложащимся. (Доброе утро ложащимся поздно спать.)*

[Причастный оборот](https://izamorfix.ru/rus/morfologiya/prichastnyj_oborot.html)
[Переход причастий в прилагательные и существительные](http://pedlib.ru/Books/4/0038/4_0038-131.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

**Причастные обороты, стоящие после слова ВСЕ, действительно требуют особого внимания.**

Справочник Д.Э. Розенталя: "***Определительный оборот, стоящий после определительного, указательного или притяжательного местоимения, тесно примыкает к нему и запятой не отделяется:*** *Всё смеющееся, весёлое, отмеченное печатью юмора было ему мало доступно (Кор.); Все опоздавшие на лекцию стояли в коридоре (...)*.

***Но если определительный оборот имеет характер пояснения или уточнения, то он обособляется (выделяется запятыми):*** *Всё, связанное с железной дорогой, до сих пор овеяно для меня поэзией путешествий (Пауст.)* — определительное местоимение субстантивировано".

**В Вашем случае** определительное местоимение ВСЕМ тоже субстантивировано (кому? *всем*), а причастный оборот имеет характер уточнения (*а именно кому? каким?*), поэтому запятая ставится:

***Доброе утро всем, поздно спать ложащимся.***

Comment: Не хочу знать ни его, ни всего (чего именно? какого?) к нему относящегося.  А здесь почему нет характера уточнения?https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460439/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-причастным-оборотом-к-нему-относящегося/460440#460440  Форум проголосовал за  вариант  без запятой (6 голосов). Никак не могу разобраться, не поможете? Смутная какая-то тема, не каждый за нее возьмется. Может быть, здесь другая причина для постановки запятой?

Comment: Вероятно, потому, что конструкция без "к нему относящегося" неотделима от местоимения "всего". Ср.: Не хочу знать ни его, ни всего. "Всего к нему относящегося"  употребляется как один член предложения.

Comment: А здесь почему "отделима", я не вижу разницы, Грамматика вариантов одинаковая: или мы субстантивируем местоимение, или причастие. Приходится выбирать.

Comment: Нет ответа... Тогда доброй ночи всем спать ложащимся. А здесь нужна запятая?

Comment: Доброе утро всем! - Местоимение-дополнение "всем" самодостаточно, звучит предложение правильно. Хотите распространить дополнение, уточнить его? Можно. Всем, поздно спать ложащимся. Добавлено определение в виде причастного оборота.

Comment: Доброе утро всем?   Это у вас, может быть,  доброе утро, а вот Онегин еще спит, только что приехал:  «Но, шумом бала утомленный И утро в полночь обратя, Спокойно спит в тени блаженной Забав и роскоши дитя».  А в заданном примере, думаете, утро?  Скорее всего, солнце уже в зените, поэтому и ставится логическое ударение на необособленный оборот. У остальных-то уже добрый день давно. И вопрос о самодостаточности  слова ВСЁ пусть автор решает,  вы бы уж предоставили ему такую возможность – поставить ударение там, где ему удобно. Свобода выбора – основная привилегия для Homo sapiens.

Comment: Немного длинно получилось, но, я думаю, вы основную мысль поняли. Мы обособляем оборот после ВСЁ, если его уточняем и поясняем, а автор, может, хочет местоимение ВСЁ именно ОПРЕДЕЛИТЬ. Всё (какое?) смеющееся, весёлое, отмеченное печатью юмора было ему мало доступно (Кор.);  У нас точно такой случай.

Comment: )) Я не ответила ещё на один ваш вопрос. Предложение "Доброй ночи всем спать ложащимся". Запятая не ставится, так как выражение "всем спать ложащимся" здесь употреблено в роли дополнения как единый член предложения.

Comment: Спасибо, хоть кто-то со мной разговаривает! А если РАЗДЕЛИТЬ АУДИТОРИИ, например: Доброй ночи всем рано встающим (им пора спать). Доброго утра всем поздно ложащимся (они же ведь днем встают, а не утром). Неужели разным будет решение? А вот насчет единого члена предложения (дополнения) я сильно сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь **причастный оборот**, в этом вы не ошибаетесь. Причастный оборот определяет (субстантивированное) местоимение ВСЕМ, так как у него неопределенное значение и оно нуждается **в определении или пояснении** (раскрытии содержания).

Да вот только определение, стоящее после определяемого слова, **может обособляться или не обособляться.**

Обособление — это норма, которая обычно указывается в правилах,  а не обособляется оборот, если является **смысловым центром высказывания** и на него падает логическое ударение.

Всё зависит от того, как вы прочитаете предложение, **куда поставите ударение.** Это ваш авторский выбор:

(1) *Доброе **Утро** // всем поздно спать **ложАщимся**.*

(2) *Доброе утро **всЕм**, поздно спать **ложАщимся.***

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ  не меняет содержание первого, он дается в целях **повышения качества ответа.**

**Основной показатель качества – это информативность.**

Речь идет об **отношении полезной для автора информации к ее общему объему**. Были даны три ответа, но я думаю, что **автор ушел ни с чем.**  Он хотел уточнить, нужно ли обособлять  причастный оборот,  и ожидал, вероятно,  такого же короткого ответа с небольшим пояснением.  Он вовсе не собирался углубляться во все проблемы и подробно изучать тему.

Ненужное обобщение вопроса с изложением всех правил и множеством примеров, подробное цитирование источников,  отклонение от заданного темы,  сложная (а иногда и надуманная) терминология  – **все это увеличивает объем текста, а также снижает его  эффективность и доступность для понимания.** Надо выбирать действительно нужную информацию и стараться даже о сложном говорить по возможности просто.

**ОТВЕТ**

***Доброе утро всЕм, поздно спать ложАщимся.***

Действительно, в этом предложении причастный оборот, стоящий **после** определяемого слова ВСЕМ, **обособляется по основному правилу** (местоимение ВСЕМ  имеет в данном случае **значение существительного**).

На месте запятой в устной речи делается пауза. Скорее всего, вы именно так произносите это предложение, и **это ваш вариант**.

**Примечание**

1. Надо сказать, что по правилам оборот **можно не обособлять,** если он тесно примыкает к определяемому слову (произношение без паузы).

В действительности же многое зависит **от структуры предложения**. В приведенном примере необособленный вариант просто **неудобен для произношения**, в других же случаях он возможен, например:  ***Доброе Утро // всем рано встаЮщим.***

Здесь делается короткая пауза в середине фразы,  но на письме она не обозначается запятой.

2. В правилах Розенталя приводятся **похожие примеры с местоимением ВСЁ** (с обособлением и без обособления оборота):

***Всё, связанное** с железной дорогой, до сих пор овеяно для меня поэзией путешествий.
**Всё смеющееся**, весёлое, отмеченное печатью юмора было ему недоступно.*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109