# Можно ли использовать союзы И… И или один союз И при наличии отрицания?

Tags: союзы, частица, ни

Обычно используется союз НИ… НИ, например: *Я не знаю ни его, ни вас.*
Сравнить: *Я не знаю и его, и вас.* Или: *Я не знаю его и вас.* Предложения выглядят некорректно.

Но это самые простые предложения, а в более сложных конструкциях применение И… И или одного И, может быть, допускается? **Какое правило регулирует использование этих союзов?**

Спасибо.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

При более близком рассмотрении тема показалась мне **слишком сложной и объемной.** Вариантов огромное количестве: соединяться могут однородные подлежащие, сказуемые, дополнения, а также целые предложения, причем везде свои особенности. Сформулировать какую-то общую теорию сложно, да это и не является целью **практической стилистики**.

Чисто интуитивно мы различаем варианты с **однозначным** выбором союзов И...И и НИ...НИ. Например: "Узнавая ее ближе, я не переставала и любоваться, и восхищаться ею..."  Здесь союз И...И подходит однозначно.

Но иногда возникают сомнения. В этом случае мы можем сказать одно: этот вариант **смотрится лучше, чем другой.** Также можно попробовать объяснить это влиянием различных факторов. Причем анализировать надо преимущественно художественные тексты или естественные разговорные ситуации, избегая тех, что кажутся построенными искусственно.

Поэтому можно ограничиться конкретной конструкцией, например **однородными дополнениями при наличии НЕ в сказуемом.** Для примера возьмем известную цитату: Уже не важно ни тебе, ни мне. Можно сказать: уже не важно и тебе, и мне; уже не важно и не тебе, и не мне? Как мы делаем выбор?

Сама тема возникла при анализе заданного ранее вопроса, где при стилистической правке было предложено **заменить НИ...НИ союзом И**. [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460439/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-причастным-оборотом-к-нему-относящегося](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460439/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F).

Предложенный вариант: Не хочу знать и его, и всего того, что с ним связано.

Мне бы хотелось услышать **мнение по поводу этого конкретного случая**.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134419/discussion-on-question-by-sharon---------).

Comment: Всё очень просто: с ‟не” перед сказуемым всегда используется ‟ни ... ни” и никогда ‟и ... и”. Найдите хоть один пример, который бы опровергал бы это.